# EXC_BAD_ACCESS using CCGLView when Home pressed

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone

I use CCGLView in cocos2d2.0 to work with cocoa Touch.
But my application will crash when I press home button. The error occured in CCGLView swapBuffers method:

`if(![_context presentRenderbuffer:GL_RENDERBUFFER])`-------EXC_BAD_ACCESS

The stack is:

5:EAGLContext_presentRenderbuffer(EAGleContext*,objc_selectorr*,unsigned int)

6-[CCGlView swapBuffers]

7-[CCDirectorIOS drawScene]

8-[CCDirectorDisplayLink mainLoop:]

.....

By the way, I do pause the director at delegate method:

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{

    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] pause];
}
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: did you check `_context` is null or not ?

Comment: if context were nil the presentRenderbuffer message wouldn't be sent

Comment: What iOS version (target and SDK) are you using for the build ? @LearnCocos2D : funny, i tracked the IOAccelResource bleed to that very same line of code.

Comment: _context is not NULL. Its value is the same with before I press home button.

Comment: IOS SDK version is 7.0, and Deployment Target is IOS 6.1.

Answer (score 7):

my solution

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] pause];   
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] stopAnimation]; // Add
}

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] resume];   
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] startAnimation]; // Add
}
```

Comment: If your game is **hidden by another view** when the app is entering the foreground (e.g. Game Center leaderboard, advertisement), which had caused your app to pause the director before the app went to the background, your code would resume the director before the top-most view is removed.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by pausing the animation in the background in the `AppDelegate`

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    [_glView stopAnimation];
}

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    [_glView startAnimation];
}
```

Comment: Do *not* include code as an image. Add it as text instead.